# determinant of two diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am having an expression that consists of addition of two N x N diagonal matrix. e.g.,
C = A + B. where both A and B are diagonal matrix. So how to take determinant of this. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diagonal matrix is a form of triangular matrix, and in the case of any triangular matrix, the determinant is the product of the entries along the diagonal. So let the entries along the diagonal of $A$ be $a_1, a_2...a_n$, and let those entries for $B$ be $b_1, b_2...b_n$. Then the entries for the diagonal of $C$ are $a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2...a_n+b_n$. I'll leave it up to you to figure out the last step.

Comment: Ok...will do it...

Comment: Got it.....and also got the intuition..